# Setting the path of an image view

Tags: android

I have an ImageView in my android application, and I have a picture on my desktop. 
I would like to relate this imageView to the path of the desktop image, so that when I run my application the image is shown . Can any one help me with the code? Thanks !

Comment: What you mean "my desktop"?

Comment: And what would you like to happen when your phone is not connected to your laptop?  Excuse me, but you really don't understand what a mobile app is.

Comment: I don't care about when it is not connected, I just want to know how to display an image on the mobile android application, any image and regarding where it is located.

Comment: I agree with @Simon, you don't seem to understand at all what is a mobile app, or even how programming works.

Answer (score 0):

You can not open a file which is not on the device on which your application is running.

Move your picture in or in `/res/drawable` directory of your application and then you will be able to view it in an `ImageView`.

If your image is called `picture1.png` and it is in the application's directory `/res/drawable`, you can set view it in an `ImageView` like this:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture1);
```

Comment: thanks ! do u have an idea if I am sending an image from a computer to the mobile phone using sockets, how to send this image directly to /res/drawable ? so that it will be displayed on the mobile phone

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.

Comment: Is it possible to read an image from an inputStream an save it on the sdcard of the phone ?!